# How can I convert a normal dataframe (lat, long columns) into Spatial Points Dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

how can I convert a normal dataframe into a spatialpoint dataframe? This is the lines of code that I used but received this error:

```
Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

//Code:

```
coords <- FinalOlistDataset[ , c("avg_lng", "avg_lat")]
data <- FinalOlistDataset[ , 1:9]
crs <- CRS("+init=epsg:3414")
FinalOlistDatasetSPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coords, 
                                                data = data, 
                                                proj4string = crs)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUego.png)

here is my output with dput(head(FinalOlistDataset)):

```
structure(list(order_id = c("e481f51cbdc54678b7cc49136f2d6af7", 
"e69bfb5eb88e0ed6a785585b27e16dbf", "34513ce0c4fab462a55830c0989c7edb", 
"85ce859fd6dc634de8d2f1e290444043", "203096f03d82e0dffbc41ebc2e2bcfb7", 
"f70a0aff17df5a6cdd9a7196128bd354"), customer_id = c("9ef432eb6251297304e76186b10a928d", 
"31ad1d1b63eb9962463f764d4e6e0c9d", "7711cf624183d843aafe81855097bc37", 
"059f7fc5719c7da6cbafe370971a8d70", "d2b091571da224a1b36412c18bc3bbfe", 
"456dc10730fbdba34615447ea195d643"), order_purchase_timestamp = structure(c(1506941793, 
1501329302, 1499975891, 1511222621, 1505745090, 1502366313), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), price = c(29.99, 149.99, 98, 17.9, 
109.9, 279), freight_value = c(8.72, 19.77, 16.13, 11.85, 8.96, 
34.19), customer_unique_id = c("7c396fd4830fd04220f754e42b4e5bff", 
"299905e3934e9e181bfb2e164dd4b4f8", "782987b81c92239d922aa49d6bd4200b", 
"d0ff1a7468fcc46b8fc658ab35d2a12c", "d699688533772c15a061e8ce81cb56df", 
"1974875b4a1d2e2ee6d586e3ba4d7602"), geolocation_zip_code_prefix = c(3149, 
18075, 4278, 13186, 4001, 5634), customer_city = c("sao paulo", 
"sorocaba", "sao paulo", "hortolandia", "sao paulo", "sao paulo"
), customer_state = c("SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP"), avg_lng = c(-46.58716127625, 
-47.4673971464706, -46.608909625125, -47.1989801198462, -46.6511147760169, 
-46.7374914230303), avg_lat = c(-23.5769829333333, -23.4740303493464, 
-23.601855984125, -22.8899823605, -23.5729394801695, -23.6063754424242
)), .Names = c("order_id", "customer_id", "order_purchase_timestamp", 
"price", "freight_value", "customer_unique_id", "geolocation_zip_code_prefix", 
"customer_city", "customer_state", "avg_lng", "avg_lat"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the dataframe that I am working with - do click on "enter image description here" to see it. thank u

Comment: Have you considered using `library(sf)`, rather than `library(sp)` for your spatial objects? `sf` is the successor to `sp`

Comment: And rather than a screenshot, can you edit your question with the output of `dput(head(FinalOlistDataset))`? This way other people will be able to use your data

Comment: have added my output of dput(head(FinalOlistDataset)). Also, how can I use sf library instead of sp to convert my df? Apologies am new to geospatial work.

Comment: Now you can use `sf <- sf::st_as_sf( FinalOlistDataset, coords = c("avg_lng", "avg_lat") )`

Comment: ah I see. This converts the df into a sf dataframe. But what if I need to run over() function in the subsequent few lines for I need to overlay this dataframe over a spatial polygon dataframe? Is there a way I can overcome the problem and still keep this dataframe as a spatial point dataframe?

Comment: A couple of options. 1. (easiest) convert the `sf` object to `sp` using `sp <- sf::as( sf, "Spatial" )` and continue to work with `sp` objects. 2. (harder, but better in the long run) go through all the [`sf` documentation](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf) and learn how to use this library